# Modifying an object or primitive using a void method

Tags: java, string, void, primitive

Consider line 2 and line 3 in the following code.....

```
class ModifyObjects {
    static void modifyString1(String s){
        s = "xyz";
    //Or any other operations
    }

    static String modifyString2(String s){
        s = "xyz";
        return s;
    //Or any other operations
    }

    static void modifyPrimitive1(int i){
        i=9;
    }

    static int modifyPrimitive2(int i){
        i=9;
        return i;
    }
}

public class Operations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String st1 = "abcd";
    String st2 = "qwerty";
    String st3;

    int i1=0, i2;

    st1 = "xyz";                          //line 1
    System.out.println("st1: " + st1);     

    ModifyObjects.modifyString1(st2);
    System.out.println("st2: " + st2);     //line 2

    st3 = ModifyObjects.modifyString2(st2);
    System.out.println("st3: " + st3);

    System.out.println("st2: " + st2);

    ModifyObjects.modifyPrimitive1(i1);
    System.out.println("i1: " + i1);            //line 3

    i2 = ModifyObjects.modifyPrimitive2(i1);
    System.out.println("i2: " + i2);    
    }
}
```

line 2 gives st2 as qwerty (does not modify. Should be xyz.)
     line 3 gives i1 = 0 (does not modify. Should be 9.)

This looks a bit odd. Here is the ouput:

```
 st1: xyz
 st2: qwerty
 st3: xyz
 st2: qwerty
 i1: 0
 i2: 9
```

Also at line 1 a new string object "xyz" is created right? I think "abcd" is just not being referenced from here.

Comment: I highly recommend starting with a beginner's book on Java or the tutorials from Oracle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Line 1 and line 2 are not very different. How do we explain that?

Answer (score 3):

in Java references to objects are passed by value...

```
    1.  st1: xyz

    Reason : you are not returning anything...

    2.  st2: qwerty

    Reason :You are not storing the returned value in st2. you should do,

        st2=ModifyObjects.modifyString1(st2);

    3.  st3: xyz

    reason : You are returning a String value and storing it in st3

    4.  st2: qwerty

    Reason : st2 is qwerty...

    5.  i1: 0  // Not reassigning value to anything

    6.  i2: 9  // returned value reassigned to i2.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some confusion on how Strings and parameter passing work in java.

1) Strings are by design **immutable objects**, and thus cannot be changed once built.  Just for clarity, something like this:

```
String s = "a";
s += "bc";
System.out.println(s);
```

Is not modifying the value of the String s, but creating a new object.  At the end of this code, you have created 2 String objects: one with value "a", in the first line, and one with value "abc" in the second line.  (This is a voluntary simplification since java compilers may decide to optimize this code, but it is correct anyway)

2) If you need a mutable String object, java gives you the `StringBuilder` object (or `StringBuffer` if you have the need of a synchronized version).  It is actually the recommended idiom if you need to append things to a String.

3) Parameter passing is **always by value** in java; this means that using a parameter in the left side of an assignation will NEVER have an effect outside the method call; instead, you just step on the value of the parameter you received.  This is true doesn't matter if the parameter is a primitive type or an object type.  If the parameter is an object type, the parameter passing is by value too, but what you copy to the method call stack is a copy of the reference to the object.  So, in your `modifyStringXX` methods, the only thing you achieve is to step on the reference to the parameter, but you will never see an effect outside that methods.